# friendly-recovery is broken, keeps returning exit status 1

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, package-management, windows-subsystem-for-linux, dpkg

I have Windows Subsystem for Linux running Ubuntu 16.04 (but with Linux Mint 19 packages). At one point, I made the mistake of installing a different kernel, which also installed `grub-pc` and `friendly-recovery`. I managed to remove `grub-pc` with `apt`, but `friendly-recovery` is stuck. I have tried the following to remove it:

```
cat > /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d <<EOF
#!/bin/sh
exit 101
EOF
chmod +x /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d
dpkg-divert --local --rename --add /sbin/initctl
ln -s /bin/true /sbin/initctl
#### Next command tried
apt remove friendly-recovery
#### Next command tried
dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq friendly-recovery
#### Finally...
dpkg --purge --force-remove-reinstreq friendly-recovery
```

None of them removed `friendly-recovery`. I always get this log output:

```
(Reading database ... 145035 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing friendly-recovery (0.2.38) ...
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `rootfs'.
dpkg: error processing package friendly-recovery (--purge):
 installed friendly-recovery package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 friendly-recovery
```

[This solution on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/143#issuecomment-209072634) didn't fix my issue.

I am now stuck not being able to change the installed packages (`apt` and `dpkg` always error processing `friendly-recovery`, no matter what package I am trying to install/remove).

What can I do to fix this? I can't think of anything but fully reinstalling WSL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the output, the post-removal script subprocess failed.

The `friendly-recovery` post-removal script is `/var/lib/dpkg/info/friendly-recovery.postrm`.

You can bypass this script by replacing its entire contents with this:

```
#!/bin/sh
exit 0
```

Here is a series of commands that can do this for you and remove `friendly-recovery`:

```
echo -e '#!/bin/sh\nexit 0' | sudo tee /var/lib/dpkg/info/friendly-recovery.postrm
sudo chmod +x /var/lib/dpkg/info/friendly-recovery.postrm
sudo dpkg -P friendly-recovery
```